# Simulation of 2 dice rolls

Tags: python, performance, simulation, dice

I wrote a program that records how many times 2 fair dice need to be rolled to match the probabilities for each result that we should expect.

I think it works but I'm wondering if there's a more resource-friendly way to solve this problem.

```
import random

expected = [0.0, 0.0, 0.028, 0.056, 0.083, 
         0.111, 0.139, 0.167, 0.139, 0.111,
         0.083, 0.056, 0.028]

results = [0.0] * 13  # store our empirical results here

emp_percent = [0.0] * 13  # results / by count

count = 0.0  # how many times have we rolled the dice? 

while True:
    r = random.randrange(1,7) + random.randrange(1,7)  # roll our die
    count += 1 
    results[r] += 1
    emp_percent = results[:]

    for i in range(len(emp_percent)):
        emp_percent[i] /= count
        emp_percent[i] = round(emp_percent[i], 3)

    if emp_percent == expected:
        break

print(count)
print(emp_percent)
```

Comment: When you say efficient, are you concerned with execution time or having clean code?

Comment: Execution time.

Comment: Why would you expect the percentages to be exactly equal ever? That's not how probability works...

Comment: They can be equal, particularly since these are rounded, but it will certainly take a long time.

Answer (score 6):

I question the validity of this exercise. I wouldn't really expect the percentages to line up for a long, long, long time. Possibly never. Running a few times I got anywhere from 290k to nearly 8 million. That's a lot of die rolls, and a pretty wide range.

---

That said, we can certainly improve your code. First, there's [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) which is more directly what you want. Let's just put that in a function:

```
def die_roll():
    return random.randint(1, 6)
```

Now we don't need that weird 7.

Next, `results` should be `int`s. After all, we're iterating upward. We only need to convert them to floats when we do the calculation. We can also use [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) for the loop:

```
results = [0] * 13
for count in itertools.count(start=1):
    results[die_roll() + die_roll()] += 1
```

Ok, now that we have our results, we need to compare against `expected`. Rather than doing a list copy, division, round on every element - let's go one at a time. After all, if the percentage for `2` doesn't line up, why even calculate the percentage for `3`?

The percentage for any one roll is:

```
round(1. * r / count, 3)
```

for `r` in `results`. And the expectation is `e` in `expected`. We want to iterate over both lists simultaneously... "zipping" through them. For that, there's [`itertools.izip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

```
if all(round(1. * r/count, 3) == e
       for r, e in itertools.izip(results, expected)):
    break
```

Lastly, don't hardcode your percentages! These have well defined values. We have a pyramid (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1) that we just multiply by 1/36. So that's:

```
def prob(x):
    count = x-1 if x <= 7 else 13-x
    return round(count/36., 3)

expected = [0.0] + [prob(x) for x in range(1, 13)]
```

So the full solution is:

```
import random
import itertools

def prob(x):
    count = x-1 if x <= 7 else 13-x
    return round(count/36., 3)

expected = [0.0] + [prob(x) for x in range(1, 13)]

results = [0] * 13

def die_roll():
    return random.randint(1, 6)

for count in itertools.count(start=1):
    results[die_roll() + die_roll()] += 1

    if all(round(1. * r/count, 3) == e
           for r, e in itertools.izip(results, expected)):
        break

print count
```

---

**Dropping Floats**

Floating point arithmetic is always slow. We could do a bit better by keeping everything integral:

```
import random
import itertools

def prob(x):
    count = x-1 if x <= 7 else 13-x
    return 1000*count/36

expected = [0] + [prob(x) for x in range(1, 13)]
results = [0] * 13

def die_roll():
    return random.randint(1, 6)

for count in itertools.count(start=1):
    results[die_roll() + die_roll()] += 1

    if all(1000 * r/count == e
           for r, e in itertools.izip(results, expected)):
        break

print count
```

---

**Generalize arbitrarily**

Sometimes, the people want an over-engineered solution. So let's give them an over-engineered solution! We can use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to help us determine the odds of particular die rolls. Everything else is straightforward:

```
def roll_until_match(sides=6, num_dice=2):
    c = collections.Counter(sum(p) for p in
                            itertools.product(xrange(1, sides+1), repeat=num_dice))

    expected = [1000 * c.get(i, 0) / (sides ** num_dice)
                for i in xrange(sides * num_dice + 1)] 

    results = [0] * (sides * num_dice + 1)

    def die_rolls():
        return sum(random.randint(1, sides) for _ in xrange(num_dice))

    for count in itertools.count(start=1):
        results[die_rolls()] += 1

        if all(1000 * r/count == e
               for r, e in itertools.izip(results, expected)):
            break

    print count
    print results
```

Comment: Now you only have to resolve the hard-coded 7, 13, and 36 ;) What if we rolled three dice? Or what if we used twenty-sided dice?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Ask and ye shall receive.

Answer (score 1):

For performance, your huge bottleneck is that you make a new list as a *copy* of `results` every  single time. This is expensive and wasteful. Instead, you could just update the number that you've just run a diceroll for. It's pretty simple, you can index `emp_percent` like you index `results`, and then run your calculation just on that index. So you're using the same calculation but only applying it to a single number and leaving the rest of the list unchanged.

```
while True:
    r = random.randrange(1,7) + random.randrange(1,7)
    count += 1 
    results[r] += 1
    emp_percent[r] = round(results[r] / count, 3)

    if emp_percent == expected:
        break
```

---

Some other notes about your initialisation. `results` doesn't need to have floats, since you're just incrementing it by 1 each time. Later, when you copy this for `emp_percent` and divide by `count` as a float, you'll get the result as a float anyway. I also think you don't need the comment explaining it. `results` is a clear name. (same with `count`). `percent_results` is a clearer name, it matches with `results` and doesn't contain a confusing shortened word.

```
results = [0] * 13
percent_results = [0] * 13
count = 0
```

Also since you have the parameters in advance, you could just use `while percent_results != expected` instead of using `break`.